# Fragment and RecyclerView errorRecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I used to have a main activity which displayed a recyclerView, and it worked perfectly. I then decided to make a fragment list with a recyclerView instead of just the recyclerView, to allow some cool displaying of the items in the list.

The Adapter Class

```
public class BeersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BeersAdapter.BeersViewHolder> {
private List<Beer> beers;
    public static class BeersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView beerImage;
        public  TextView beerName;
        public  TextView beerDesc;
        public  BeersViewHolder (View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            beerImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.beerImageLayout);
            beerName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.beerNameLayout);
            beerDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.beerDescLayout);
        }
    }
    public BeersAdapter(List<Beer> b){
        beers = b;
    }
    @Override
    public BeersAdapter.BeersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beer, parent,false);
        return new BeersViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BeersViewHolder holder, int pos) {
        holder.beerName.setText(beers.get(pos).getName());
        holder.beerDesc.setText(beers.get(pos).getShortDescription());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
    return beers.size();
    }
}
```

The onCreateView in the fragment class

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mainbeer_list, container, false);

    RecyclerView rV =  view.findViewById(R.id.BeerRV);
    rV.setHasFixedSize(true);

    rV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    beers = Beer.getDummyBeers();
    BeersAdapter mAdapter = new BeersAdapter(beers);

    rV.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    rV.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    return view;
}
```

I know if I  `return view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mainbeer_list, container, false);`  unused it don't give an error, but nothing have changed either. By this I mean I can run the code on the `onCreateView` , but if I return the view I used (as far as I know, it should not be changed) it causes the error.

The error i get running the debugger

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a
>   null object reference

**Edit:**
I know what a NullPointer is. I just don't know why I get it. Because my app worked perfectly normal, with the same ordering, the only different is I now am using a fragment, and creating the RV in the fragment instead of the MainActivity. Based of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621060/display-a-recyclerview-in-fragment)

**Edit 2:**
the Layout for `fragment_mainbeer_list.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView         
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/BeerRV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

and for the `main_activy.xml` where the fragment lives

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ListFragment"
        android:name="com.example.beers_fragmnet.MainBeerFragment"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="328dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout="@layout/beer" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Side info**

The app just displays a list of beer, and before trying to add the fragment when clicked on a Beer it open a detailed activity and displayed the info about the beer.

I now wanted to make it work for tablet the same way a lot of email apps work, when you click on an Email, instead of opening a new activity, it opens the email in the same activity (incase of bad explanations here is a [photo](http://i1.wp.com/www.techplayce.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Gmail-Blog-Tablet-image2.png) of what I am trying to say )

Comment: Try to moving `rV.setHasFixedSize(true);` after you've set the Adapter to RecyclerView.

Comment: @Zoe
I can see that it is a NullPointerException, and I know what that means (I primary program in C/C++). I just don't know why I am getting it, especially when the same code in `onCreateView` worked for MainActivty but throws a NullPointer now. I obvious have missed something, and I spent hours trying to see if anyone had a similar problem, but I couldn't find anything, so here I am

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך I tried moving it, and commenting it out (as the piece of code is just for a performance boost, so it can calculate the max size of the RV). But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Can you provide your XML code?

EDIT 2: Try to put **FrameLayout** instead of **fragment**

Take a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43475197/10326629)

Comment: As far as I understand the XML code, I have BeerRV inside of the fragment_mainbeer_list.xml
However I just created the Fragment_mainbeer_list and added my xml code from my previous RV inside it.
And I have added the XML code, thank you for taking your time to help me

Comment: I just tested your code and it works fine. Which line of code generates this error?

Comment: I get a long error message but non of it is any code i wrote.
[Here is the error code](https://i.imgur.com/B8wTTOg.png)

Comment: Try to use <FrameLayout instead of <fragment in XML

Comment: Yes, That worked. But what is the difference between FrameLayout and fragment?
also I am still wondering why fragment isn't working